# Scala Dataframe have duplicate but with Null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose dataframe have below value:

```
|AccNo  |        DOB|
+------+-------------------+
| 11    |1970-05-30 00:00:00|
| 11    |               null|
| 22    |               null|
```

If DOB is not null then it should take that row, else null row should be there.
Output should be as below:

```
|AccNo  |        DOB|
+------+-------------------+
| 11    |1970-05-30 00:00:00|
| 22    |               null|
```

I am trying as below. Need to put it in if/else or something like that:

```
df.groupBy("AccNo").count().filter($"count" < 2)
df.filter($"DOB" isNotNull)
```

Should I create two dataframe and then union them? Any suggestion or help much appreciated!

Comment: What if there are 2+ not null rows for a given `AccNo`? Which one to keep?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.max.html) as aggregation function. `max` ignores null values if any other value within  the group is found:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy('AccNo').agg(F.max('DOB')).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+
|AccNo|  max(DOB)|
+-----+----------+
|   11|1970-05-30|
|   22|      null|
+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```scala
df.filter(!$"DOB".isNull).join(df.select($"AccNo").distinct, Seq("AccNo"), "right").show
```

Answer (score 0):

For remove nulls for accounts with not-null "DOB" records, Window can be used for find accounts with only nulls, and filtering nulls for others:

```
val df = Seq(
  (11, "1970-05-30 00:00:00"),
  (11, null),
  (22, null)
).toDF(
  "AccNo", "DOB"
)
// action
val accNoWindow = Window.partitionBy("AccNo")
df
  .withColumn("onlyNulls", first($"DOB").over(accNoWindow).isNull)
  .filter($"DOB".isNotNull || $"onlyNulls")
  .drop("onlyNulls")
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------------------+
|AccNo|DOB                |
+-----+-------------------+
|11   |1970-05-30 00:00:00|
|22   |null               |
+-----+-------------------+
```